# list-keychains shows multiple Keychains that do not exist

Tags: macos, keychain

I have a Mac that performs builds for my iOS application.

I'm noticing a strange misconfiguration on the Keychain List. In particular, `security list-keychains` command shows multiple Keychains that do not exist (those are shown also when I use Keychain Access application).

This is confirmed if I try to delete one of them by means of `security delete-keychain /Users/XXX/Library/Keychains/keychain-name-db` command.

> security: SecKeychainDelete: The specified keychain could not be found.

Is there a way to remove the internal booking of macOs?

Thanks,
Lorenzo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've fixed the issue removing the following preference file available at `/Users/USER/Library/Preferences/com.apple.security.plist`.